# SH: save awk command output in variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have following code that prints

1. Disk Usage: 78/223GB (35%)
2. CPU Load: 2.00
3. Memory Usage: 5650/16302MB(34.66)

But I want to use out as variables in bah script insated of printing them.
How can i do that ?

**What I want:**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# I want 3 variables which have values from awk 
# How can i convert awk command below to do that ?
$disk_usage
$CPU_usage
$Memory_usage
```

**CODE:**

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    while("df -hP " | getline) {
        if ( $NF == "/" ) {
            printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5
        }
    }
    while( getline  < "/proc/loadavg" ) {
        printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)
    }

    while( "free -m"| getline) {
        if( $0 ~ /Mem:/) {
        printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with bash

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

disk=
cpu_usage=
memory_usage=

while true; do
  read -r disk
  read -r cpu_usage
  read -r memory_usage
  break
done < <(awk -f tst.awk)

printf '%s\n' "$disk" "$cpu_usage" "$memory_usage"
```

where `tst.awk`

```
BEGIN {
    while("df -hP " | getline) {
       if ( $NF == "/" ) {
          printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5
       }
    }
    while( getline  < "/proc/loadavg" ) {
       printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)
    }

    while( "free -m"| getline) {
      if( $0 ~ /Mem:/) {
       printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2
       }
    }
}
```

Instead of a separate script for awk, one can add the `awk` code inside the Process substitution.

```sh
done < <(awk 'BEGIN {
    while("df -hP " | getline) {
       if ( $NF == "/" ) {
       printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5
       }
    }
    while( getline  < "/proc/loadavg" ) {
       printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)
    }

    while( "free -m"| getline) {
       if( $0 ~ /Mem:/) {
       printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2
       }
    }
  }'
)
```

Without the `while` loop, using `{ }` for command grouping.

```sh
{
  read -r disk_usage
  read -r cpu_usage
  read -r memory_usage
} < <( awk 'BEGIN {
  while("df -hP " | getline) {
   if ( $NF == "/" ) {
      printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5
    }
  }
   while( getline  < "/proc/loadavg" ) {
     printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)
  }
  while( "free -m"| getline) {
     if( $0 ~ /Mem:/) {
       printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2
     }
   }
  }'
)

printf '%s\n' "$disk_usage" "$cpu_usage" "$memory_usage"
```

Comment: Thankx. What i wanted. Can I make it a single .sh file insated of separate ```tst.awk```

Comment: Yes, You can embed the `awk` code inside the Process substitution.

Comment: I seem to have issue embeeding it. can you share how ?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, rather than using bash commands(multiple commands) in single `awk` you could make it easy by making their different sections of commands like:

```
cat script.bash
#!/bin/bash
FILESYSTEM="/"
##For disk space
DISK_USAGE=$(df -hP "$FILESYSTEM" | awk '{printf("Disk Usage: %s %s\n",$3,$2,$5)}')
##For Cpur
CPU_DETAILS=$(awk '{printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)}' /proc/loadavg)
##For Memory
MEMORY_DETAILS=$(free -m | awk '/Mem/{printf("Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will define 3 variables and print to screen:

```
#!/bin/bash

DISK_USAGE=$(awk 'BEGIN {
    while("df -hP " | getline) {
        if ( $NF == "/" ) {
            printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5
        }
    }
}')

CPU_LOAD=$(awk 'BEGIN {
    while( getline  < "/proc/loadavg" ) {
        printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)
    }
}')

MEMORY_USAGE=$(awk 'BEGIN {
    while( "free -m"| getline) {
        if( $0 ~ /Mem:/) {
        printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2
        }
    }
}')

echo $DISK_USAGE
echo $CPU_LOAD
echo $MEMORY_USAGE
```